# Organising List of Objects to Nested Arrays using Recursive String Path

Tags: android, json, typescript, kotlin, recursion

I have a list of items, these items can have children, and the children can also have children. The API I'm using returns a list of these items in a single Array of Objects and provides a `path` property to consume the list and organise it how you choose. Each child adds an extra incrementing `-000n` to the `path` starting at `0001`. I can't work out how to consume the `path` value to organise the list of Objects into nested Arrays where each item has it's own respective `children[]` Array.

I'm using Typescript/JS and Kotlin (Android Framework).

Been trying to figure this out for a while, I'd appreciate some community input on the problem. Hope I've explained it well enough, thanks!

Example:

```
|--group (0001)
  |--item (0001-0001)
    |--item (0001-0001-0001)
      |--item (0001-0001-0001-0001)
      |--item (0001-0001-0001-0002)
  |--item (0001-0002)
    |--item (0001-0002-0001)
      |--item (0001-0002-0001-0001)
        |--item (0001-0002-0001-0001-0001)
      |--item (0001-0002-0001-0002)
  |--item (0001-0003)
|--group (0002)
  |--item (0002-0001)
```

Payload:

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "cameras",
      "type": "group",
      "path": "0001"
    },
    {
      "name": "camera-1",
      "type": "equipment",
      "path": "0001-0001"
    },
    {
      "name": "charger",
      "type": "power",
      "path": "0001-0001-0001"
    },
    {
      "name:": "cable",
      "type": "power",
      "path": "0001-0001-0001-0001"
    },
    {
      "name": "adapter",
      "type": "power",
      "path": "0001-0001-0001-0002"
    },
    {
      "name": "camera-2",
      "type": "equipment",
      "path": "0001-0002"
    },
    // etc
    {
      "name": "lights",
      "type": "group",
      "path": "0002"
    }
    // etc
  ]
}
```

Preferred outcome:

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "cameras",
      "type": "group",
      "path": "0001",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "camera-1",
          "type": "equipment",
          "path": "0001-0001",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "charger",
              "type": "power",
              "path": "0001-0001-0001",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name:": "cable",
                  "type": "power",
                  "path": "0001-0001-0001-0001"
                },
                {
                  "name": "adapter",
                  "type": "power",
                  "path": "0001-0001-0001-0002"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
            "name": "camera-2",
            "type": "equipment",
            "path": "0001-0002",
            // children as above
        }
      ]
    },
    {
        "name": "lights",
        "type": "group",
        "path": "0002",
        // children as above
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a map to store the items by their path while you build the item tree. Here's an example:

```kotlin
data class Item(
    val name: String,
    val type: String,
    val path: String,
    val children: MutableList<Item> = mutableListOf(),
)

val itemsList = <flat list of items, parsed from json>
val pathMap = mutableMapOf<String, Item>()
val itemsTree = mutableListOf<Item>()
for (item in itemsList) {
    pathMap[item.path] = item
    if ('-' in item.path) {
        val parentPath = item.path.substringBeforeLast('-')
        val parent = pathMap[parentPath]
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.children += item
        }
    } else {
        itemsTree += item
    }
}
```

Here `itemsList` is the original list of items, in a flat hierarchy, and `itemsTree` is a list of top-level items only, each with a `children` attribute containing children items. This does require however that all "parents" appear before any of their children in `itemsList`, but could be easily modified to account for that not being the case.

I'm not sure if you wanted Kotlin or TypeScript, but the concept is easily interchangeable between the two, all you need is a map-like data structure.

Comment: This is great and seems to work as expected when I log the result of `itemsTree`, thank you! I'm struggling to understand the relationship between the Map and the Item's. How do the children in the Map get added to the tree? Sorry if I'm being dumb.

Comment: A map allows you to associate a value with a key. Here the key is the path. Since the parent's path is contained within the child's path, we can obtain the parent item from the map, and add a new child. If the item is top-level (no `-`), then it is added to the root of the tree. Items are never created in this piece of code, only new references are made.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Great solution, thank you very much for taking the time to explain.